# Why thread blocking is happened when DataIntegrityVioldationException is occured

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a question about JPA and hibernate.

In my application, simultaneous request was received and they had the same primary key.

So, sometimes DataIntegrityVioldationException is occured in my code.

for example,

```java
void save(Member member) {

    try {
        MemberRepository.save(member);
        anotherQuery();
    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        logging();
    }
}
```

And I found when `DataIntegrityViolationException` is occured, there is a response delay.
I checked log of exception in executing queries.
when `JPARepository.save()` is called, it doesn't executed because it is not flushed.
but `anotherQuery()` is called, it makes hibernate flush because it is using native query.

So, in executing `anotherQuery()`, `DataIntegrityViolationException` is thrown because simultaneous save request for the same primary key.

But I wonder why some blocking is happened between PK collision and executing catch block.
I try to find the reason, so I found some log that "On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements" in `AbstractBatchImpl`. After that, it tooks 3~5 second to execute catch-block.
Have you ever seen this situation? Thank you for read my question.